# Avoiding the use of eof in this case

Tags: c++, eof, getline

I have posted the following code where I am reading from an input file -- storing information in a structure -- and then writing to an output file. I know that the `eof` function is not *safe* and hence one must use the `getline` function to check whether the end of file has been detected or not; however, in this particular code, I have not been able to use the `getline` function  and hence has finally relied on the `eof` function. Hence, can you please suggest an alternative to the `eof` function or let me know how I can use the `getline` function when I am trying to initialize an array of structures . I have used two **asterisk** symbols to indicate where I want to use the `getline` function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
//student structure
struct student
{
  char name[30];
  char course[15];
  int age;
  float GPA;
};

ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile;

student getData();
void writeData(student writeStudent);
void openFile();

int main (void)
{
  const int noOfStudents = 3; // Total no of students
  openFile(); // opening input and output files

  student students[noOfStudents]; // array of students

  // Reading the data from the file and populating the array
  for(int i = 0; i < noOfStudents; i++)
  {
        if (!inFile.eof()) // ** This where I am trying to use a getline function.
            students[i] = getData();
        else
            break ;
  }


  for(int i = 0; i < noOfStudents; i++)
    writeData(students[i]);

  // Closing the input and output files
  inFile.close ( ) ;
  outFile.close ( ) ;

}

void openFile()
{
  inFile.open("input.txt", ios::in);
  inFile.seekg(0L, ios::beg);
  outFile.open("output.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
  outFile.seekp(0L, ios::end);

  if(!inFile || !outFile)
  {
    cout << "Error in opening the file" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }

}

student getData()
 {
  student tempStudent;
  // temp variables for reading the data from file

  char tempAge[2];
  char tempGPA[5];

  // Reading a line from the file and assigning to the variables
  inFile.getline(tempStudent.name, '\n');
  inFile.getline(tempStudent.course, '\n');
  inFile.getline(tempAge, '\n');

  tempStudent.age = atoi(tempAge);

  inFile.getline(tempGPA, '\n');
  tempStudent.GPA = atof(tempGPA);
  // Returning the tempStudent structure
  return tempStudent;
 }

void writeData(student writeStudent)
 {
  outFile << writeStudent.name << endl;
  outFile << writeStudent.course << endl;
  outFile << writeStudent.age << endl;
  outFile << writeStudent.GPA << endl;
 }
```

Comment: Is this a homework question?  Just asking because it doesn't have the homework tag and the code seems academic.  The question itself is fine.

Comment: No, this not a homework question. I am just practicing structures and how I can write them to a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to write an `operator>>` for your student type. Something like:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, student& s) {
  in >> s.age; // etc.
  return in;
}
```

Which then allows you to write:

```
int studentNo = 0;
students[maxStudents];
while (studentNo < maxStudents && (in >> students[studentNo]))
  ++studentNo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not write this way?

instead of

```
inFile.getline(tempStudent.name, '\n');
inFile.getline(tempStudent.course, '\n');
inFile.getline(tempAge, '\n');
```

You may

```
while(inFile.getline(tempStudent.name, '\n'))
{
    inFile.getline(tempStudent.course, '\n');
    inFile.getline(tempAge, '\n');
    //do stuffs
}
```

Comment: Yes, I can certainly do that, but actually I was trying to do it in the main function. Any suggestions how I can use the getline in the main without modifying the functions?

Comment: If you insist, the most you can do is that instead of checking for EOF, just use getline() for 'name', pass the 'name' to the slightly modified getdata().